# Xcode invalid zip file

Tags: xcode, zip

I am uploading my Xcode `.zip` file to https://www.diawi.com and when I upload it, it says:

> An error occurred:
>   4001003: Invalid .ipa file: content couldn't be read, doesn't seem to be a valid zip-compressed file (za9)

My zip file consists of:

[image]

Why is it invalid? (I compressed it by Ctrl-Click and compress)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My zip file consists of:

Well, that's wrong. They want your built *.ipa* file, not your source code.

> I compressed it by Ctrl-Click and compress

An *.ipa* file *is* a zip-compressed file. You don't need to zip it *again*.